# CUDA and Sconscript

Tags: cuda

I am running a cuda project. But somehow I am not able to set the flag -arch=sm_20 in the
sconscript file which has been written by someone else. I need to use printf in kernel for debugging and I have little experience of sconscript python.

Answer (score 3):

The specifics depend on the way you have SCons set up to work with CUDA.  I use these scripts: http://github.com/BryanCatanzaro/cuda-scons

With this setup, all you need to do is invoke SCons with your preferred architecture:

```
scons arch=sm_20
```

And nvcc will be invoked with the -arch=sm_20 flag.

Details of your setup may be different, but if you look through your SCons script, you should see how to change this flag.